# Marking detections in shapefile using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to create a plugin that automatically detects objects in a selected layer and marks these items with a circle (not a point, as the radius is important) and outputs all detections as a shapefile.

I'm using the plugin builder for the base construct of the plugin and added a way to select a specific layer. In the next step I detect things and output a pandas dataframe (**df**) with the detections (x, y, radius, ...)

Currently I'm using the following code, however, it only marks the objects with points, but I would prefer circles as the radius is important.

```
layerFields = QCore.QgsFields()
layerFields.append(QCore.QgsField("id", QVariant.Int))
layerFields.append(QCore.QgsField("object name", QVariant.String))
layerFields.append(QCore.QgsField("condfidence", QVariant.Double))
layerFields.append(QCore.QgsField("radius", QVariant.Double))
layerFields.append(QCore.QgsField("unkown", QVariant.Double))

writer = QCore.QgsVectorFileWriter(fn, "UTF-8", layerFields, QCore.QgsWkbTypes.Point,
                QCore.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326"), "ESRI Shapefile")

for count, value in enumerate(df.values): #<-- add objects from dataframe to qgis
    print(value)
    feat = QCore.QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(QCore.QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QCore.QgsPointXY(value[0], -value[1])))
    feat.setAttributes([int(count), 'Unknown_test_type', float(random.random()), float(value[2]), float(value[3])])

    writer.addFeature(feat)

iface.addVectorLayer(fn, '', 'ogr')

del(writer)
```

How would i need to modify this code so it marks the objects with a circle instead of a point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making a point layer, change it to polygon. [Buffer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.buffer) your point and use the buffer geometry in each feature.

```py
## make a polygon layer, instead of point
writer = QCore.QgsVectorFileWriter(fn, "UTF-8", layerFields, QCore.QgsWkbTypes.Polygon,
                QCore.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326"), "ESRI Shapefile")

for count, value in enumerate(df.values): #<-- add objects from dataframe to qgis
    print(value)
    feat = QCore.QgsFeature()
    ## make a point of the coordinates
    point = QCore.QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QCore.QgsPointXY(value[0], -value[1]))

    ## buffer the point
    ## 1 is buffer distance, which presumably is variable in your case and comes from a column in your df
    ## 16 is the number of segments used in the buffer
    circle = point.buffer(1, 16) 
    
    ## set the circular buffer to the feature geometry
    feat.setGeometry(circle)
    feat.setAttributes([int(count), 'Unknown_test_type', float(random.random()), float(value[2]), float(value[3])])

    writer.addFeature(feat)
```